# ¿ Cómo prohibir cualquier touch a la pantalla durante 10 segundos?

Tags: java, android, screen

Tengo un audio que suena 10 segundos, (es la anterior pregunta que puse de como bloquear un botón) pero me he dado cuenta que como también tengo un `bottom bar`, si toca cualquier cosa del `bottom bar` también se me crashea, por tanto para no bloquear cada cosa ( que sería más difícil) **estoy buscando cómo prohibir cualquier touch a la pantalla**, es decir, que no pueda hacer absolutamente nada , deshabilitar toda la pantalla.

No he encontrado información sobre esto ya que no es muy común hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Has mirado si con el método getWindow() puedes conseguir tu objetivo?

Comment: Lo he intentado, pero se queja cuando pongo "getWindow()" , me sale en rojo.

Comment: Estoy mirando este link, por si te ayuda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378644/how-to-call-getwindow-outside-an-activity-in-android

Comment: no sé bien donde poner lo que dices dentro: ``void someMethodThatUsesActivity(Activity myActivityReference)`` que es la mejor respuesta que está en la pregunta , algo raro.

Comment: Creo que la forma en que abordas el problema no es correcta, imagina tener que agregar validaciones para bloquear todos los botones!. Que provoca el error, que el audio esta reproduciendose? A partir de esto podemos dar una solución real! @RfMvs

Comment: Tienes razón por eso esta pregunta la dejé de lado porque es muy contraproducente, mi única solución tras muchas horas dandole vueltas es mi nueva pregunta que has comentado hace 2 minutos :)

Answer (score 2):

Los componentes tienen una propiedad clickable que puedes poner a true o false.

Pero si tuvieras que tocar esta propiedad en muchos componentes, puedes capturar el evento Touch sobreescribiendo el método onTouchListener del layout padre de los componentes.

Por otro lado necesitarías un contador de tiempo. Ahí puedes usar por ejemplo el objeto CountDown, en la documentación oficial viene un ejemplo: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html